# Profiling C code on Windows when using Eclipse

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, profiling, gprof

I know I can profile my code with `gprof` and `kprof` on Linux. Is there a comparable alternative to these applications on Windows?

Comment: Which compiler are you using on Windows?

Comment: You can use gprof on windows with the MinGW port of the GCC compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commercial software:

- Rational Quantify (expensive, slow, but very detailed)
- AQTime (less expensive, less slow, a bit detailed)

Free software:

- Very sleepy ([www.codersnotes.com](http://www.codersnotes.com))
- Luke StackWalker ([lukestackwalker.sourceforge.net](http://lukestackwalker.sourceforge.net/))

These commercial alternatives change the compiled code by 'instrumenting' (adding instructions) to it and perform the timing withing the added instructions.  This means that they cause your application to slow down seriously.

These free alternatives use sampling, meaning they are less detailed, but very fast.  In practice I found that especially Very Sleepy is very good to have a quick look at performance problems in your application.

Comment: I tried both Very Sleepy and Luke StackWalker, but they're unable to tell me anything. They don't seem to have access to my source code. gprof however works just fine. How come? I really like GUI-based profilers, but they're not working.

Comment: This error was produced by Luke StackWalker: `ERROR: SymGetModuleInfo64, GetLastError: 1114 (Address: 7C90E514)`

Comment: I've opened a seperate question for this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302596/luke-stackwalker-returns-error-when-running-gprof-works-fine

Answer (score 3):

There's a MinGW port of gprof that works just about the same as the Linux variant. You can either get a full [MinGW installation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/) (I think gprof is included but not sure) or get gprof from the [MinGW binutils package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/GNU%20Binutils/).

For Eclipse, there's [TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/) but it doesn't support profiling C/C++ as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can profile code [with Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)

Comment: I'm an Eclipse user, so that's no option for me.

Comment: @Pieter: then please specify this important clause in *the question*

Comment: In any case, Visual Studio standard and express editions don't include a profiler. With pro, there's a simple (command-line) profiler which I believe is a separate download, and isn't easy to use. What Microsoft want is for (rich) people to buy Team Suite.

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason for profiling? Do you want to a) measure times and get a call graph, or b) find things to change to make the code faster? (These are not the same.)

If (b) you can use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/1562802#1562802), using the Pause button in Eclipse.

---

Added: Maybe it would help to convey some experience of what performance problems are actually like, and where you can expect to find them. Here are some simple examples:

- An insertion sort (order n^2) where the items being sorted are strings, and are compared by a string-compare function. Where is the hot-spot? in string-compare. Where is the problem? In the sort where string-compare is called. If n=10 it's not a problem, but if n=1000, suddenly it takes a long time. The point where string-compare is called is "cold", but that's where the problem is. A small number of samples of the call stack pinpoint it with certainty.
- An app that loads plugins takes a long time to start up. A profiler says basically everything in it is "cold". Something that measures I/O time says it is almost all I/O time, which seems like what you might expect, so it might seem hopeless. But, stack samples show a large percentage of time is spent with the stack about 20 layers deep in the process of reading the resource part of plugin dlls for the purpose of translating string constants into the local language. Investigating further, you find that most of the strings being translated are not the the kind that actually *need* translation. They were just put in "in case" they might need translation, and were never thought to be something that could cause a performance problem. Fixing that issue brings a hefty time savings.

So it is common to think in terms of "hotspots" and "bottlenecks", but most programs, especially the larger ones, tend to have performance problems in the form of function calls requesting work that doesn't really need to be done. Fortunately they display themselves on the call stack during the time that they are spending.

Comment: I'm interested in profiling to see which parts of my code take longer to execute so that I can discover eventual inefficiencies.

Comment: @Pieter: Finding inefficiencies is (b). I'm trying to spread the word about this. Here's another take on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308026/which-has-been-the-most-reliable-fastest-windows-c-profiler-that-you-have-used/2311117#2311117

Comment: Sounds complicated for a C newbie like me. My ideal profiling application should be able to lay a heat map over my code to see which commands take the longest time to execute. Some code is supposed to take more processing time, I know, but there are plenty of cases where this would help detect the aforementioned inefficiencies.