# Looking for a free, time sampling profiler for C++

Tags: c++, profiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best Free C++ Profiler for windows (if there are)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows-if-there-are)

I'm looking for a free, time sampling profiler for C++

I've never used a profiler before, and the versions of Visual Studio I have don't come with one, basically I'd be happy with anything free, effective, and reasonably simple; with suitable instructions

Comment: Yes, sorry - I'm using Visual Studio 2005 / 2010 on Windows Vista.

Comment: Or also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308026/which-has-been-the-most-reliable-fastest-windows-c-profiler-that-you-have-used

Comment: The free time-sampling profiler I've relied on, since before profilers were invented, is [random-pausing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Answer (score 4):

I have used Very Sleepy in the past and have been quite happy with it.

http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy

Comment: I think Sleepy was the one I adapted last year when I needed one. I had to decouple out all the WinMX which in my opinion should have been an optional extra.

Answer (score 0):

Please try my profiler, called cRunWatch

http://ravenspoint.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/timing/