# elapsed time in C

Tags: c, time, elapsed

```
#include <time.h> 
time_t start,end; 
time (&start);
//code here
time (&end); 
double dif = difftime (end,start); 
printf ("Elasped time is %.2lf seconds.", dif );
```

I'm getting 0.000 for both start and end times. I'm not understanding the source of error.

Also is it better to use time(start) and time(end) or start=clock() and end=clock() for computing the elapsed time.

Comment: This works fine for me. Have you verified the values of start and end with a debugger? (Note: to test it I put a "sleep(1)" between the time(start) and time(end).)

Comment: If you need time measurements at finer resolution, have you tried `clock()`?

Comment: @sverre: `clock()` does not measure the absolute passage of time. It measures the quantity of time spent specifically on this one process. Important distinction. If you're profiling, you may want this; otherwise you probably don't.

Answer (score 7):

On most (practically all?) systems, `time()` only has a granularity of one second, so any sub-second lengths of time can't be measured with it.  If you're on Unix, try using `gettimeofday` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you do want to use `clock()` make sure you understand that it measures **CPU time** only. Also, to convert to seconds, you need to divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Answer (score 2):

Short excerpts of code typically don't take long enough to run for profiling purposes. A common technique is to repeat the call many many (millions) times and then divide the resultant time delta with the iteration count. Pseudo-code:

```
count = 10,000,000

start = readCurrentTime()

loop count times:
    myCode()

end = readCurrentTime()

elapsedTotal = end - start
elapsedForOneIteration = elapsedTotal / count
```

If you want accuracy, you can discount the loop overhead. For example:

```
loop count times:
    myCode()
    myCode()
and measure elapsed1 (2 x count iterations + loop overhead)

loop count times:
    myCode()
and measure elapsed2 (count iterations + loop overhead)

actualElapsed = elapsed1 - elapsed2
(count iterations -- because rest of terms cancel out)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`time`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/time.html) has (at best) second resolution. If your code runs in much less than that, you aren't likely to see a difference.

Use a profiler (such a gprof on *nix, [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) on OS X; for Windows, see "[Profiling C code on Windows when using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302425/profiling-c-code-on-windows-when-using-eclipse)") to time your code.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using between the measurements is running too fast. Just tried your code printing numbers from 0 till 99,999 and I got

> Elasped time is 1.00 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is taking less than a second to run.