# Windows Eclipse CDT profiler

Tags: windows, eclipse-cdt, profiler

I am using Eclipse CDT (Juno) under Windows 7, can anyone recommend a good profiler for that environment, please? If there is none, please advise about stand alone application which might be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gprof MinGW port in Windows7.

For more details see this post

[Profiling C code on Windows when using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302425/profiling-c-code-on-windows-when-using-eclipse)