# Omnet++ :std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, omnet++

I run simulations based on ad hoc networks and when the numbers of nodes is big (100 nodes) and simulation time is long (more than 300s), I get the following error :

> Error in module (MobileOverlay)
>   MobilePeerNetwork.MobilePeer[73].overlay.moverlay (id=3023) at event
>   #508013243, t=372.42387824: std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc.

I would to know if there is a way  to find the exact position of the problem without using Valgrind option because I work in windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because during object creation `new[]` fail to allocate the requested storage space.

So, either your hardware can not support the simulation which you are trying to run, or you forget to free up memory allocated previously, so your machine runs out of memory.

Here is a useful post: ["std::bad_alloc": am I using too much memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378797/stdbad-alloc-am-i-using-too-much-memory).

---

Based on the OMNeT++ guide:

> Profiling support is based on the valgrind program,
>   http://valgrind.org. Valgrind is a suite of tools for debugging and
>   profiling on Linux. It can automatically detect various memory access
>   and memory management bugs, and perform detailed profiling of your
>   program. Valgrind support is brought into the OMNeT++ IDE by the Linux
>   Tools Project of Eclipse, currently in incubation state.

So the initial suggestion would be to switch to a Linux machine -- maybe virtual machine, to get your work done. In the long run, using OMNeT++ on Linux will benefit you much more.

Obviously, you are looking for a quick (and possibly dirty) solution, so you can refer to this: [Windows Eclipse CDT profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470444/windows-eclipse-cdt-profiler)

Comment: Thanks  a lot, I install necessary package to work in linux, I hope that it'll work.